# Как пользоваться Emmet на JSfiddle?

Tags: emmet, jsfiddle

Какие клавиши нажимать, чтобы запускался Emmet?

Comment: http://docs.emmet.io/

Comment: мне не руководство к плагину нужно, а как им пользоваться на JSFiddle. А там комбинация клавиш совсем другая, нежели на Notepad или Sublime.

Comment: если попробуете клавиши описанные на сайте отлично работают и в jsfiddle. Но не все, из-за особенностей браузера

Answer (score 1):

Emmet нормально работает на jsfiddle. Но надо иметь в виду, что в разных окнах (html, css, js) результаты будут разными.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующие: TAB или CTR+E.